# How can i set loop property in jmeter for non-gui mode

Tags: jmeter

How can we set a loop property in jmeter so if value is not given it will run for forever.I know how to create a property for loop but not sure about how to make it run for forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it run forever, the loop count should be `-1`.